# append link in-game of saved image

Tags: html, animate-cc, save-image

I made a dress up game in Animate CC using HTML5 Canvas. And at the end, the user can save the character as an image.

My problem has been how to append this image on the game.

At first, i simply created a link, which would appear below the game (solo, the person would need to scroll down to see the link; if it was embeded, I'm not sure how it would work, so i tried alternatives). And because it could confusing to find it, i also created an alert box.

I've now managed to get this image to automatically open in a new window, which is better - however, this doesn't work in Chrome, as it opens a blank window.

So I wonder if there is a another/better way to do this..?

Ideally, it would be great to trigger an object in-game that would appear near the save image button, that could contain the link (or as many as the user saves). But I don't know enough about programming to do that...

This is the current code:

```
    var hiddenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
hiddenCanvas.width = canvas.width * 0.388;
hiddenCanvas.height = canvas.height;
var canvasContext = hiddenCanvas.getContext('2d');
canvasContext.drawImage(
    canvas,
    0,
    0, 
    canvas.width * 0.388,
    canvas.height,
    0,
    0, 
    canvas.width * 0.388,
    canvas.height);

var aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href', hiddenCanvas.toDataURL("image/png"));

aTag.innerHTML = "Criámos uma imagem do teu Doutor. Salva-a aqui! :O)";

aTag.download = "ONV_oTeuDoutor.png";

window.open(aTag);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture a screenshot of your Canvas at any instant using the following:

```
var src = canvas.toDataURL();
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = src;
```

You can then add it to your DOM using :-

```
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

Comment: Yes, "document.body.appendChild(image);" was how I did it first. But I wasn't sure if the link would be very noticeable. I was trying to come up with an alternative to this.